# How to go to the next line of a text box programmatically in wp7?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm using a text box to enter some details. What I want is, when I press enter of the soft keyboard, I want the cursor to move to the next line.

in xaml,

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown" 
    Background="Transparent" 
    TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged_1" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Height="198" 
    argin="10,172,0,0" 
    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="436"/>
```

In Code behind,

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
           // How to handle??
        }
    }
```

How to handle??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Enable MultiLine property.

Comment: @ChilakaUmesh there is no `MultiLine` or `EnableMultiLine` property in the wpf textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to handle the Enter key in that way.

You can simply set the property [AcceptsReturn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.acceptsreturn%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to true:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox"
     AcceptsReturn="True"
     .....
```